# Как задать текст вьюркам которые созданы в XML?

Tags: android

Есть вьюрка на андроиде, созданная а идее в редакторе, она содержит несколько текст вью, как задавать текст этим текст вью?

Хочется использовать эту вьюрку как шаблон, чтобы резать её много раз.

Comment: *[offtop]*

> Хочется **использовать эту вьюрку** как шаблон, **чтобы резать её много раз**.

А вы садист, однако. Но не надо резать бедных [птичек][1].

*[/offtop]*


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Если хотите что бы вам ответили "на понятном программисту языке", то и задавайте вопросы не на своем местном районном сленге с какими-то воробьями(вьюрками), а общепринятыми стандартами, или хотя бы близким к ним языком.

Comment: Спасибо, буду стараться точнее формулировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С трудом расшифровав ваш "модный сленг", на сколько я понял, вы создали layout в XML, в котором несколько TextView.  
что бы задать им текст, нужно получить ссылки на них. Для этого есть такой метод

```
findViewById();
```

В который параметром передается ID элемента.  
ID элемента задается в XML в поле Id.  
В итоге, если ID в XML на пример `textView1`, то что бы получить ссылку на этот TextView:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Кроме того метод  `findViewById();` возврашает тип View, который придется привести к TextView, что бы установить в него текст.  
В итоге получится что-то в роде

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText("Какой-то текст");
```

А вот вторая часть вашего вопроса и правда не поддается расшифровке, как заметил [@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)

Answer (score 5):

> как задавать текст этим текст вью?

Гм.

```
yourTextView.setText("…");
```

Или вы что-то другое имеете в виду?

> Хочется использовать эту вьюрку как шаблон, чтобы резать её много раз.

А эту часть вопроса я много раз перечитывал, но так и не понял. Попробуйте её переформулировать.